# Read element from nested map by key. mongodb spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

there is the following structure

```
@Id
private String beaconMac;
private SortedMap<LocalDate, Map<Integer, HistoryData>> history;
```

[image]

How i can read internal value from 'history' map by key? how to make a right query? or meybe in spring data there is a blank like

`NestedObject` repo.find`NestedObject`ByDate(LocalDate date);

Very grateful!

Comment: You can use `$objectToArray` on mongodb

Comment: Thanks Nimrod, maybe you can share a simple example ?

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: I wanna specify beaconMac and date like "C145109D4D5C", 2020-20-02 and get something like that {beaconMac: "my desired beaconMac" , history:  { "my desired date" : value{} }

Comment: I need the history object to contain only the specified date, without other keys (dates)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
db.collection.find({
  beaconMac: "C145109D4D5C"
},
{
  "history.2020-20-02": 1,
  beaconMac: 1
})
```

The first part is the `match`, in which you choose what documents you want. The second is the projection, in which you format the fields you want to see.

As You can see on this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7gmOsi2_X_H)

Comment: If it is working for you, please mark the answer as accepted so it will be easier to others to find it